# Date from API call not being accepted in Laravel as a dateTime field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, eloquent

I am getting dates from an API call. The date is formatted in this way

> 2017-10-19T15:30:00

I want to store this date in my MYSQL database using Laravel Database Migration, currently I am using

```
$table->dateTime('datetime');
```

When I store it using a dateTime field as above, all I get is

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

When I use a timestamp format, I don't get accurate dates, I just get the current time and date.

How can I solve this? Any help would be appreciated, and please let me know if you want further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, Laravel uses the Carbon class, which makes things a lot easier to modify dates. In your case, you want to do this:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $date);
```

There are two ways you can implement it: you can modify it before you save it to your database, or you can add a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators) on your model.

```
public function setDatetimeAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['datetime'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $value);
}
```

You may want to build in some validation to see which format the date/time is in before you try to convert it.

Comment: Thank you. It apparently, solves the problem... but, when I make a query it does not match it, while previously it was matching. Is there something else I need to add somewhere in order for this to work everywhere

Comment: If you want to port it back out with that same format, you can use as accessor function. It's very similar, but change the name of the function to `getDatetimeAttribute($value)` and inside do `return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $value);`

Comment: For queries, I'd suggest modifying it in your controller before you do your query.

Comment: So, in my controller do I need to use Carbon class again so that it matches the query returned from the GET request? I just want it to correctly query to a date like '2017-10-19' obtained from the GET request.

Comment: Correct. The Carbon class is fairly versatile.

Answer (score -1):

in the model you should put:

```
protected $dates = ['datetime'];
```

Use Carbon

```
$dt = Carbon::parse('1975-05-21 22:23:00.123456');
```

to save:

```
$model = new Model;
$model->date = $dt; // you can use the carbon object directly
$model->save();
```

Comment: I want to change the migration table so that it recognizes and accepts the value obtained from the API call

Comment: I need to use a dateTime field as I would need to post it to the API somehow using that dateTIme field, I am just wondering why the dateTime field is not working

Comment: because of the T in the String

Comment: any way I could ignore the T when I call the API?

Comment: parse it like the post from aynber